# On off checkbox styling

Tags: css

I'm trying to turn a brand new template into my login script and for some reason the text "ON" for the checkbox isn't aligned properly like the template is as well as there doesn't seem to be a right border when on is selected. I've been trying to match up the elements and css to troubleshoot but not having any luck.

http://www.kansasoutlawwrestling.com/kowmanager/login

http://themeforest.net/item/zice-admin-colorful-admin-templates/full_screen_preview/1980638

I tried changing the padding as suggested by the two people below but I'd rather not change the css because it works on the template shouldn't it work without changing the css on mine.

Any other ideas?

I'm hoping someone sees something.

Comment: What you say about the css from the template is wrong, though. If you "inpect element" on the span, you can see that the padding-left is overwritten in the template. So the answers below should fix your error. As for the right-border, it looks similar in my browser (chrome).

Comment: I'm using the latest version of FF.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `13px` padding set on the span. Remove it and it will align properly.

It's on line 1187 of your `zice.style.css` file:

```
label.iPhoneCheckLabelOn span {
    padding-left:13px
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this declaration to this value:

```
label.iPhoneCheckLabelOn span {
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```